Psycho dude moves in with a couple and wreaks havoc
I wonder if anyone can provide pointers to the identity of this movie I watched at least 12 years ago but left an impression on me:
Some psycho dude makes a nice impression on a (newlywed) couple and they let him stay with them temporarily until he finds housing. He turns out to be a creep and starts wreaking havoc in different ways, I believe one of them being a sexual assault on the woman. He may have also killed the husband (or BF), cannot remember. It is a psychological drama.
It's an American movie, no really famous actors. The psycho was not a well known actor, certainly not Michael Keaton, and he was not motivated by rational goals, such as some profit scheme.

Was it U.S.? Do you remember the actors or what they looked like? Particular scenes? Approximate decade?

yes, American movie, no really famous actors

Sounds like Dead Calm but without the nautical setting...

Sounds a little like Pacific Heights?  Except the guy is a renter, and he ends up going psycho on them so he can get the property in a foreclosure sale.

A couple works hard to renovate their dream house and become landlords
  to pay for it. Unfortunately one of their tenants has plans of his
  own.


no, it wasn't that but it's close.  the psycho was not a well known actor, certainly not M. Keaton.  and he was not motivated by rational goals, such as some profit scheme.
